# Want to add more option in "Sexy Login"

Tags: widgets, login

I am using [Sexy Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sexy-login/) in my new website. Its a beautiful plugins. But i need to add some more options. I want to add more button for both who are logged in & who are not logged in like "Write New Post" "Add New Media".

There is another problem which is by default its widgets wide limit is 240px but i want to make it 300px.

So please help me to solve those problems.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a simple build-in WordPress command.

An example of your situation:

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
         echo '<a href="#" class="write-new-post">Write New Post</a>';
    } else {
         echo '<a href="#" class="Login">Login</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: where i should put this code?

Comment: @Mezba you place the code where you want it to appear (like HTML) in one of your pages. If you want it in the sidebar, place it somewhere in your `sidebar.php`.

Comment: Pls see this image, i want add button here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vw0a5dpx6rabpwm/sexylg.jpg